# Handle Host Window events in a VSTO Add-in

Tags: vsto, office-2013

I'm creating a PowerPoint VSTO Add-in where I would like to run custom logic when the host PowerPoint window is resized/moved/maxed/minimized.

The Office versions I'm required to target are 2013 and 2016.

Since I was unable to find any managed events on `DocumentWindow`, I'm trying to somehow observe the window through its handler (I guess it's `addIn.Application.ActiveWindow.HWND`).

Not only was I unable to register to anything, the pinvoke API seems jawdropping anyway with arbitrary values and enums which are really hard to find.

How can I register to these events I was mentioning above?

Comment: Since the Office 2013 API provides the window handle (HWND), this becomes a non-VSTO-specific question.

Comment: @Chris I was hoping for a VSTO-specific solution, for example a way to directly access the window in a managed manner, that is why I provided context.